# tcpdump advanced filtering to filter DNS RCODEs

Tags: tcpdump

On `Ubuntu Xenial` I want to use `tcpdump` to filter DNS responses with errors RCODes (ServFail, NXDomain, etc.). So every RCODEs except '0'.

(See [IANA DNS RCodes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#dns-parameters-6))

So I have to use a filter based on the 11th byte in the UDP packet. The 4 low bits contains the RCODE.
I want to test if the value is different than 0. So I left-shift by 4 bits to get only these 4 low bits.

This command doesn't work:

> tcpdump port 53 and 'udp[11] << 4 > 0'
>
> ```
> listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
>   14:07:04.148693 IP ns-cache0.oleane.net.domain > 192.168.151.53.50372: 17799 2/0/0 CNAME video-stats.l.google.com., A 216.58.204.142 (82)
>   14:07:04.150768 IP ns-cache0.oleane.net.domain > 192.168.151.53.50372: 39389 2/0/0 CNAME video-stats.l.google.com., AAAA 2a00:1450:4007:812::200e (94)
>   14:07:04.150798 IP ns-cache0.oleane.net.domain > 192.168.151.53.60464: 60219 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (104)
>   14:07:04.152703 IP ns-cache0.oleane.net.domain > 192.168.151.53.40235: 3472 1/0/0 PTR ns-cache0.oleane.net. (75)
> ```

I also get NoError DNS responses...

But using this command works:

> tcpdump port 53 and 'udp[11]&0x0F > 0'
>
> ```
> listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
>   14:07:42.014626 IP ns-cache0.oleane.net.domain > 192.168.151.53.54270: 44447 NXDomain 0/1/1 (109)
>   14:07:42.016611 IP ns-cache0.oleane.net.domain > 192.168.151.53.41840: 57750 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (104)
> ```

Why is the left-shifting not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's nowhere specified that the left shift is executed in an 8-bit register, and that the high bits are dropped. (In fact, the shift probably uses a register of whatever native size the machine has, e.g. 32 bit or 64 bit).

So don't use left shifts to try to mask out values...

Comment: Indeed you're right... The filtering seems to be done by the kernel :
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/510c8a899caf095cb13d09d203573deef15db2fe/net/core/filter.c

So yes, I will avoid left-shift. Thanks!

Comment: Yet, it is used in the tcpdump manpage... :/ http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html#lbAF

Comment: This example `(((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)` does something different (hint: left shift is not used in a `... > 0` expression, but in a `... - ...` expression). So don't use left shifts **and comparison with zero** to **mask out values**. Use left shift in other circumstances as appropriate.